# Return a reject table from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, fault, fault-tolerance

I want my stored procedure to fill a 'reject' table for the line from my staging and which can not be injected in my target table (for example a line without description which is NOT NULL in my target).

I don't have an idea about the structure of the reject table.

I can edit if you need more info!

There is my table staging

```
CREATE TABLE [staging].[B]
(
    [ID] [varchar](250)  NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [Approved] [bit]  NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](1000) NULL;
)
```

And this is my target table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A]
(
    [ID] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [Approved] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL;
)
```

This is my stored procedure code:

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedure]
    (
        @processType Varchar(4),
        @stagingTable Varchar(64),
        @destinationTable Varchar(64),
        @errorMessage NVarchar(MAX) = null OUTPUT
    )
AS
BEGIN

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @isLocaltran BIT = 0

   BEGIN TRY
   
    IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        SET @isLocaltran = 1
    END
    DELETE 
    FROM  staging.B
    WHERE staging.B.[Description] IS NULL 
    OUTPUT 
    deleted.* 
    INTO [dbo].[RejectTable]

    MERGE dbo.A AS TARGET
    USING staging.B AS SOURCE ON (TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID)
       SELECT 
           TARGET.[Address],
           TARGET.[Approved],
           TARGET.[Description]

       EXCEPT

       SELECT  
           SOURCE.[Address],
           SOURCE.[Approved],
           SOURCE.[Description]
                                )
         THEN
            UPDATE 
                SET TARGET.[Address] = SOURCE.[Address],
                    TARGET.[Approved] = SOURCE.[Approved],
                    TARGET.[Description] = SOURCE.[Description] 
               
    WHEN NOT MATCHED 
        THEN
            INSERT (,[ID], [Address], [Approved], [Description])
            VALUES (...)
```

)

Comment: That isn't how SQL works; if a single row fails a `CONSTRAINT` the entire DML statement does. You'll need to perform checks *first* in the SQL and do something *else* with that data that fulfils the requirements of *not* meeting the table's (and filter that data out when you perform the DML statement). Otherwise you could use ETL software that does have this capacity, as many do have the ability to "reroute" erroneous data.

Comment: Yes , unfortunnatly with ETL i can't bcz they ask me to do that in a stored procedure for a first time , I injecte all the data in the staging without constrains and after that i use the S.P to merge btw the target and the source !

Comment: Then you'll need to do as I mentioned above, and validate the data first, and do *something* with that data and then, in your `MERGE`, ensure you filter out any data that would fail your constraints.

Comment: You can do the ETL validation and scrubbing in the proc, just not with a single MERGE statement. For example, `DELETE FROM Staging.b WHERE Id IS NULL OR Adddress IS NULL ... OUTPUT deleted.* INTO RejectTable;`.

Comment: Also, @nada , please try to avoid "txt language" like "bcz" and "btw". [so] is a programming Q&A website for professionals, so we expect well written language, but also for many users here English isn't their 1st, or even 2nd or 3rd language. As such, they may have no idea that "bcz" is *because*, or "btw" is *by the way*. Thanks.

Comment: @DanGuzman for the rejectTable i must have an rejected table for each object?

Comment: @Larnu Okey Thank you

Comment: *"i must have an rejected table for each object?"* Yes, @nada , as each table will have a (very) different definition.

Comment: @Larnu thank you a lot..i gonna try it and let you know

Comment: @DanGuzman I am asking where i can  add it? in the when not match clause or i must to add another clause( when not match by source then DELETE FROM Staging.b WHERE Id IS NULL OR Adddress IS NULL ... OUTPUT deleted.* INTO RejectTable )

Comment: As I mentioned, not in the `MERGE` statement. Delete the bad rows using a `DELETE` query like my example and output the deleted rows into into a reject table. Then execute the `MERGE` statement.

Comment: @DanGuzman i edited my Stored Procedure.. i get an error on OUTPUT.. i can not figure out what the wrong

Comment: @nada, sorry but I misplace the `OUTPUT` clause in my example comment. Should be like `DELETE FROM Staging.b OUTPUT deleted.* INTO RejectTable WHERE...`

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks; but still not working .. [An explicit value for the identity column in table 'dbo.RejectTable' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.] I set it to ON but no working

Comment: @DanGuzman I think instead of create a table RejectTable ...i must Declare the RejectTable into The PS @RejectTable?

Comment: If your rejects table has n IDENTITY column, you need to specify and explict column list without the IDENTITY column like: DELETE FROM Staging.b OUTPUT deleted.ID, deleted.Address, deleted.Approved, deleted.Description INTO RejectTable (deleted.ID, deleted.Address, deleted.Approved, deleted.Description) WHERE Id IS NULL OR Adddress IS NULL ... `

Comment: Whether you use a permanent table or table variable depends on what you plan to do with the rejects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much for @Dan Guzman's comment. It helped me so much.

```
DELETE FROM Staging.b OUTPUT deleted.* INTO RejectTable WHERE..
```